# woocommerce display product category on checkout page

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, categories

I am trying to get product category on check out page for showing a special message for shipping for specific category. For this I have created action filter on `woocommerce_available_shipping_methods` in theme functions.php

This is my code for getting category here -

```
global $post;
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',);
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'product_cat', $args);
print_r($terms);
```

But it's not giving category on checkout page. Only product ID is one thing I am getting here.

Any help please.

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code, especially the

```
global $post;
```

and then

```
$post->ID
```

part is getting the `$post_id` of the page you are on from the [`$post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post) [`global` variable](http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables), not of the product(s) in your cart, which would be what you are looking for.

Aside from that, the `$args` parameter of `wp_get_post_terms` has no argument `taxonomy`, besides you already defined the `taxonomy` as second parameter of the function call.

---

*Disclaimer:*

- I answered this because the problem on hand has nothing to do with the third-party plugin, questions about those are generally [off topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but with understanding how WordPress works.
- So the woocommerce specific part below does not justify asking off topic questions, but is meant to help someone out anyway.

---

Getting the ids of the items in your cart can be done somewhat like this:

```
global $woocommerce;
$cart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$cart_items_ids = array();
foreach ( $cart as $item_key => $item_value ) {
    $cart_items_ids[] = $item_value[ 'data' ]->id;
}
```

Comment: +1 for not doing any automatic close. I agree part of this is still on-topic.

Comment: In a way things have gotten a bit more complicated lately; or at least more restrictive. @helgatheviking